# Changing PHP configuration dynamically

Tags: php, configuration, register-globals

I have multiple system running on PHP 5.3 that are 15-10 years old, I can't go on those and change anything.

Problem is: some of those system are using PHP `register_globals = on` that is depreciate on PHP 5.3 and doesn't even exist in PHP 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

I am developing a new system and would like to turn PHP `register_globals = off` But I can't because all those old system that NEEDS it.

So I thought about dynamically changing the `register_globals` to `off` in my script using `string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )` but the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) baffles me a bit:

**Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.**

Does that mean that if I have two script running at the same time lets say... One of my old system that really needs `register_globals = on` and my new system that use `ini_set()` to `register_globals = off` that the old script will be running with the newly changed setting? Or will it keep the setting in my PHP.ini file and the new system will run on the `ini_set()` configuration?

**--EDIT--**

After some test (see code below) @Jacob was right and it seems PHP create a context for each script and that `ini_set()` only change the configuration of the script its in.

TestWithIni_Set.php

```
<?php
ini_set('register_globals', '0');

$i = 0;
while(true)
{
    if($i == 0)
    {
        phpinfo();
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

TestWithoutIni_Set.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

So I ran `TestWithIni_Set.php` first, then will `TestWithIni_Set.php` was executing (the infinite while loop) I ran `TestWithoutIni_Set.php`.

Unfortunatly, it seams like I can't change `register_globals` value with `ini_set()`. I tried the following:

```
//Knowing that ini_set() parameters are strings I tried those anyway.
ini_set('register_globals', '0');
ini_set('register_globals', 0);
ini_set('register_globals', 'off');
ini_set('register_globals', 'Off');
ini_set('register_globals', false);
ini_set('register_globals', 'false');
```

Then to make sure I didn't had something wrong in my code I tried:

```
ini_set('log_errors', '0');
```

Just to see if it would work and it did. Then value of `log_errors` for the script with `ini_set()` was off and the value of `log_errors` for the script without `ini_set()` was on.

But now I have a different problem.

How can I change the value of `register_globals` for only the running script if I can't change it using `ini_set()`?

Comment: The old script will run with the old setting. PHP scripts run in their own context per-invocation and cannot affect each other directly in that way.

Comment: @Jacob Not that I doubt your word but if you could provide a pieces of documentation on this (a link or something) in an answer I would gladly give it a checking mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `.user.ini` file to my new system dir with the only line being `register_globals=off`.

I also went and uncomment the following line in my PHP.ini file:

```
user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"
```

I also made sure only a local user had the rights to make changes to that dir. So somebody couldn't go and upload a new user define .ini file for my server within this dir.

For exemple: IIS user can only read the file in this dir and can't add/modify/remove any file.